# Can anyone tell me how can this be achieved?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Prompting a yes no interface to user so as to re-execute a block of code.lets assume that block of code is echo "Hello"

Comment: can you please give an example script of what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: echo "Hello" This command will print Hello one time but I need something that can allow user to print it again and again with yes no prompt. Sorry as this is all what I've got :D

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because even though this may be relevant to bash, but mostly is interpreted as about general programming, and unrelated to administering an Ubuntu system in any way.

Comment: Rather ask on Unix & Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something simple like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while true; do
  echo "Hello world"
  read -p "Re-run this program? (y/n)" answer

  if [ "$answer" == "n" ]; then
    break
  fi
done
```

That will print "Hello world" inside a loop, and require an input of "n" to break out of it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a loop to repeat a sequence of commands. Use `read` to get input from the user:

```
#!/bin/bash
want_to_print=yes
while [[ $want_to_print == yes ]] ; do
    read -p 'Hello ' want_to_print
done
```

Comment: An even simpler way...nice!

Answer (score 0):

There is a multitude of ways to do this, in a variety of languages. Since bash has already been done, I'll throw in `AWK`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{ MSG="yes/no?";  while ( 1 ){ print MSG;getline line; if (line == "yes") {print "HELLOWORLD"}  else {exit}}}'               
yes/no?
yes
HELLOWORLD
yes/no?
yes
HELLOWORLD
yes/no?
no

xieerqi:
$
```